# How do I get my linked HTML pages to redirect properly and not take me deeper in?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to link html pages created on bootstrap without success. The buttons don't even click out so it's not like I get taken to another page with an error message. Just nothing. But today I observed something that might help someone more savvy than me identify the problem.

So, I'm trying to link other pages on the index.html (as an example, the services page).

Instead of taking me to "https://chozeqfarms.dashnexpages.net/services/" it looks like it wants to take me to https://chozeqfarms.dashnexpages.net/index/services.html, which I observe when hovering over the service button.

My code snippet for the navigation bar is below, and the href looks regular to my untrained eyes. But I must be doing something wrong, please what could be wrong and how do I fix it?

```
<div class="row navbar-row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 navbar-container mynav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="navbar-brand" id="go-to-top">Chozeq Farms</a>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-full">
      <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-md" id="tmNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="services.html">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="trainings.html">Trainings</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-lg-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#tmNavbar">
      ☰
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to go `https://chozeqfarms.dashnexpages.net/services/` change your href to `services/`

Comment: Hi xNoJustice, it hasn't helped. But maybe I didn't implement it correctly? This is what I used: <a class="nav-link" href="services/">Services</a>

Comment: try `<a class="nav-link" href="/services">Services</a>` if problem continues add direct link to href `<a class="nav-link" href="https://chozeqfarms.dashnexpages.net/services/">Services</a>`

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I already did those before now and they didn't work.

Comment: Just a quick update and further request for help, I realised that doing the "/services" made it so that when I hover on the button, it points to the right place however, the buttons themselves are not clickable.